# Codeigniter destroy sessions separately

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use two different sessions for admin and user,and I want to destroy each session separately but when I destroy one session using `$this->session->sess_destroy();` it destroys both sessions. Please help me.

```
$admin_data = array (
        'admin_email' => $this->input->post('admin_email'),
          'is_admin_logged_in' => 1
               );

$this->session->set_userdata($admin_data);
redirect('admin_profile');    

public function admin_profile() { 

        if ($this->session->userdata('is_admin_logged_in')){

                $this->load->view("view_admin_profile");                
        }
        else {redirect('login');}
    }

public function logout() { 
    $this->session->unset_userdata($admin_data);
    redirect("login");
    }
```

Comment: this above code working fine that session what you creating session using $admin_data are unseted on logout function then whats the problem

Comment: the problem is that I still can open my profile page(without logging in) after logging out

Comment: are you calling the function admin_profile to view the admin profile or url like this localhost/projectname/controller/admin_profile

Comment: url like this localhost/projectname/controller/admin_profile

Comment: I have just changed  $this->session->unset_userdata($admin_data); to  $this->session->unset_userdata('is_admin_logged_in'); and it worked fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `$this->session->unset_userdata('name of session');`

for more info check the user-guide

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: unset_userdata() just removed the data from the session but session was not destroyed. I still have access to my profile after logging out.

Comment: can you give me this print_r($this->session->all_userdata());

Comment: use this in construct method of all controller to check the that user login or not if(!$this->session->userdata('admin_id')) {redirect('login')}

Comment: i want output after using $this->session->unset_userdata('is_admin_logged_in'); this line

Comment: I check session like that. I have just edited my question. Please have a look on my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :-

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('some_name');
```

`unset_userdata()` can be used to remove it, by passing the session key

For e.g :

If your admin session name is 'admin_id' and user session id is 'user_id' then you can seperately destroy both the session like this :-

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('admin_id'); // for admin

$this->session->unset_userdata('user_id'); // for user
```

Comment: unset_userdata() just removed the data from the session but session was not destroyed. I still have access to my profile after logging out.

Answer (score 0):

To destroy the session in codeigniter simply do this;

```
function logout() { 

        $this->session->sess_destroy();

}
```